# C#/PHP Send image with Webclient.UploadData + POST data

Tags: c#, php, file-upload, image-uploading

This is function I use to send image and it work ok but I want to send Image + some POST data to be able to send image + some userid to specify where to save the image.

```
    public static void SendImage()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Screenshot screen = new Screenshot();
            byte[] SendBMP = screen.Capture();
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "IMAGE uploader";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "binary/octet-stream";
            client.QueryString.Add("UserID", ID);
            client.UploadData(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/upload.php/"), SendBMP);
    }
```

In php I have this -image saving works but I cant pass additional data

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("TEST.jpg", file_get_contents("php://input"));
$xfiles = mime_content_type ("TEST.jpg");
error_log($xfiles, 0);
error_log(strlen($rawData), 0);


if ($_POST["UserID"]))
{
    error_log("POST OK", 0);
}
```

But the POST never fires up in the end I would like to have it like this

```
if ($_POST["UserID"]))
{
error_log("POST OK", 0);
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents($_POST["UserID"]."/TEST.jpg", file_get_contents("php://input"));
$xfiles = mime_content_type ($_POST["UserID"]."/TEST.jpg");

//check type
error_log($xfiles, 0);
//check size/lenght?!
error_log(strlen($rawData), 0);
}
```

When I do

```
error_log($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 0);
```

It returns POST everytime but I cant get the post data in any way..

Also is there any possibility to check mime_content_type before saving the file?